# Detect multiple zeroes in a string

Tags: php

I have a list of numbers coming in mostly looking like this: 1234567912345.

But some of them have a big number of zeroes both before and after the usual number.
Making them look like this: "000000001765032019308000000".
For the moment I will call them special numbers.

My initial try was using strpos to check if it contains "00000" which should be enough to confirm that this is indeed one of the special numbers but that doesn't work.

It's also not possible to just check the length of the number.

So my question is, how do I detect if a number is one the special numbers?

Comment: How many zeros is a "big number"?

Comment: 6-8 before and 6-8 after the rest of the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match) to determine whether there are 6-8 0's at the beginning and end of the number:

```
$numbers = array('1234567912345', '000000001765032019308000000',
                 '000000000000445000000', '0000004000000');

foreach ($numbers as $num) {
    echo "$num is " . (preg_match('/^0{6,8}[1-9](\d*[1-9])?0{6,8}$/', $num) ? '' : 'not ') . "special\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1234567912345 is not special
000000001765032019308000000 is special
000000000000445000000 is not special
0000004000000 is special
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I was looking for. Thank you very much. I really need to learn how to use preg_match.